# Change the color of <li> parents on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML code

```
<ul>
<li>LINK 1</li>
<li>LINK 2</li>
<li>LINK 3
  <ul>
    <li>link 3.1</li>
     <li>link 3.2
       <ul>
          <li><a href="#" style="color:red;">link 3.2.1</a></li>
           <li>link 3.2</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
       </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
```

CSS

```
 li:hover{color: blue;font-weight:bold;}

 li:hover li {color: red;font-weight:normal;}

 li:hover li:hover{color: blue;font-weight:bold;}
```

This is my code , but when I print the text within the anchor tag (`<a href="#" style="color:red;">link 3.2.1</a>`) the CSS is not working and the color change that I try to implement for the link element is not working .  How can I make it work in the same way , even if the text is inside the anchor tag? I wish to change the HTML code as follows

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" style="color:red;">LINK 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" style="color:red;">LINK 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" style="color:red;">LINK 3</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" style="color:red;">link 3.1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" style="color:red;">link 3.2</a>
       <ul>
          <li><a href="#" style="color:red;">link 3.2.1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" style="color:red;">link 3.2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
       </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: so you like to change the color of li and anchor in hover ?

Comment: Do you want to change color of anchor tag on hover to blue?

Comment: yes ,i want to change the color of li and anchor on hover .

Comment: the same same color change should reflect for its parent li also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the inline style from anchor and try with this css

```
li a{ color:red;} 
li:hover, li:hover a{color: blue;font-weight:bold;}

li:hover ul a{color: red;font-weight:bold;}
li:hover ul li:hover > a{color: blue;font-weight:bold;}
```

**[updated jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/7oh14mwL/2/)**

Comment: when i add a fourth level ul it is not working , all the anchor tag in the 4th li elements are displayed as blue , i want it to work for the list with any number of levels

Answer (score 0):

First you have to define color for a tag.

Add class for first ul

```
<ul class="list">
...
</ul>
```

for example

```
.list li a{
color:#000;
}

.list li a:hover
{
color:blue;
}

.list li:hover > ul li a
{
color:red;
}
.list li ul li a:hover
{
color:blue;
}
```

Look this http://jsfiddle.net/3wc7181c/

Comment: on hover of link3.2.1 the color of link3.2 and link3 should change

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want?

```
li:hover{color: blue;font-weight:bold;}
li:hover li {color: red;font-weight:normal;}
li:hover li:hover li, 
li:hover li:hover li a{color: blue !important;font-weight:bold;}
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/hativo/2/)

Comment: i want to change the color of the anchor tag in its parent nodes as well

Comment: on hover of link3.2.1 the color of link3.2 and link3 should change

Answer (score 0):

Just add following css and remove inline css

```
a{ color:red;}

li:hover{color: blue;font-weight:bold;}

 li:hover li {color: red;font-weight:normal;}

 li:hover li:hover{color: blue;font-weight:bold;}

li:hover li:hover a:hover{color: blue;font-weight:bold;}
```

Updated demo http://jsfiddle.net/wcs1mhg6/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this you will get what you want

```
li a:hover{color: blue !important;font-weight:bold;}
li a:hover li {color: red;font-weight:normal;}
li a:hover li:hover, 
li li li a:hover{color: blue !important;font-weight:bold;}
```